# I am making a chat forum and I am having probels with ng Model

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I am getting and error why trying to use `[(ngModel)]="message"` to build a form, the error I am getting is, `Identifier 'message' is not defined`. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member ng. I have `imported {NgModule} from '@angular/core';` in the `app.module.ts` so I can't see why it isn't working.

The code I an trying is:

```
<input
    class="chatInput"
    [(ngModel)]="message"
    (keydown)="handleSubmit($event)"/>

    <button class="chatButton" (click)=Send()></button>
```

Any help would be great, thank you .

Comment: 1) are you importing `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`? 2) you need a `name` attribute when using `[(ngModel)]`. 3) what does your `ts` component look like?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define the data variable "message". Initialize its value to empty string e.g

message: "",

Comment: I already did that in the ts file. It's okay I have fixed it, the vaiable was spelt wrong -_-